# Solaris 10 invalid ARP requests from 0.0.0.0? Link up/down every hour or 2

Tags: networking, solaris, arp, solaris-10, sctp

The guys at the data center where I'm hosting a server running Solaris 10 are telling me that my server is making a lot of invalid arp requests. This is an example of a portion of what was sent to me from the logs (with Mac addresses and IP addresses changed).

```
[mymacaddress]/0.0.0.0/0000.0000.0000/[myipaddress]/[Datestamp])
```

It's being logged every hour.

I don't see anything in the arp tables (arp -a) or routing tables (netstat -r) and I don't see anything relating to 0.0.0.0 when snoping the arp requests.

The only place I see any reference to 0.0.0.0 is if I do netstat -a for the SCTP

```
SCTP:
        Local Address                   Remote Address          Swind  Send-Q Rwind  Recv-Q StrsI/O  State
------------------------------- ------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------- -----------
0.0.0.0                         0.0.0.0                              0      0 102400      0  32/32  CLOSED
```

But not really sure what that means. Doesn't seem like I can disable SCTP. There are some [tunable SCTP parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-0404/chapter4-98.html) but it's not something I'm familiar with. Do I have to add changes to /etc/system? Looks like sctp_heartbeat_interval might be what I need to change?

If it makes any difference, I have a few solaris zones running on this server, each with their own IP address on a virtual interface. eth0:0, eth0:1, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this and how to stop it? I think the switch I'm connected to doesn't like it and momentarily drops the connection.

Is there anyway to at least block those requests using ipfilter or something else?

**Update:** This was happening more frequently but now it seems to be happening roughly every hour or every two hours. It's not consistent. I tried setting setting the link speed and duplex to match the switch port and that seemed to make it stop happening for a few hours but then it started again.

Comment: Are you using IPMP?  Have you tried capturing the ARP traffic to see if that gives you and leads to the cause?  Or possibly something as simple as needing a patch?